# How to post a date as a parameter using MockHttpServletRequestBuilder with jUnit?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit

I've been able to do tests normally with MockHttpServletRequestBuilder while I was only posting strings as parameters.

How can I post a date as a parameter, as it seems that my FormattingConversionService below does not work into jUnit tests, and my spring infrastructure is not converting String values to Calendar ones.

```
@Bean
    public FormattingConversionService mvcConversionService() {
        DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionService = new DefaultFormattingConversionService();
        DateFormatterRegistrar formatterRegistrar = new DateFormatterRegistrar();
        formatterRegistrar.setFormatter(new DateFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        formatterRegistrar.registerFormatters(conversionService);
        return conversionService;
    }
```

The test I'm trying to do is:

```
    @Test @Transactional
    public void shouldSaveABill() throws Exception {
        String dueDate = "05/25/2017";
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post("/saveBill")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                .param("id", "1")
                .param("description", "Food")
                .param("dueDate", "05/25/2017")
                .param("value", "150");

        mockMvc.perform(request)
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is(302))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.forwardedUrl("/someUrl"));
    }
```

While debugging the test, I got the error:

```
Field error in object 'bill' on field 'dueDate': rejected value [05/25/2017]; codes [typeMismatch.bill.dueDate,typeMismatch.dueDate,typeMismatch.java.util.Calendar,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [bill.dueDate,dueDate]; arguments []; default message [dueDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Calendar' for property 'dueDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Calendar] for value '05/25/2017'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [05/25/2017]]
```

Please, what is the best approach to test the persistence of an entity that has a field of Calendar type using jUnit, spring and MockHttpServletRequestBuilder ? Is there another way to do this and achieve the same goal ? I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: exception suppose you need to pass a `java.util.Calendar` type parameter to the method.

Comment: suppose you need `Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2017,4,25);` to pass as due date.

Comment: @RajithPemabandu the problem is exactly that, the .param method does not accept any other type but String.

Comment: Any reason you are you two separate formats yyyy-MM-dd in your DateFormatter but mm/dd/yyyy in your test?

Comment: @Sea It's because when the user is inputting the date, it is on the mm/dd/yyyy format, and date are being exhibited in another format.. I'm changing that already. Thanks.